# Is it appropriate to reschedule a phone interview?

Tags: interviewing

This past Sunday I was contacted by a recruiter to schedule a phone interview for later this week at 1:00 PM. However, she just notified me that the time will actually be 4:00 PM, because she didn't take into account that the interviewer will be in a different time zone (1:00 PM their time, 4:00 PM my time). Unfortunately, I have another appointment during that time, and cannot take the call without canceling the meeting. Is it appropriate to ask to reschedule for earlier in the day or a different day?

Comment: "(1:00 PM my time, 4:00 PM their time)" Wait, does this mean the time hasn't actually changed for you at all? Or did you have these backwards?

Comment: @TheSoundDefense, yes I had them backwards

Comment: I would be put off by a recruiter that phones me on a Sunday, and the fact that the recruiter missed details is another warning sign. A recruiter is your ambassador to an employer. They give the employer the first impressions of you before they even see your resume. If you want to be professional then find professional representation.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini - I am sure you never make a mistake... as for calling sunday, not everyone works an american standard workweek.

Comment: I didn't intend to offend. Sorry. I just wanted to indicate that a recruiter represents you and impressions matter.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is appropriate. Your recruiter does not expect you to drop all of your commitments at a moment's notice for a phone interview. Tell them you have a conflict that you can't get out of, and suggest some more appropriate times or dates as a jumping-off point for rescheduling. Any company worth working for will be understanding of this.